# ViewBinding not working on android studio 4.1.2?

Tags: java, android, android-viewbinding

I am facing a problem with view binding  in android studio 4.1.2.

When I call:

```
binding.answerTextView.setText("jkhlgkgkjgjg");
```

It does not work, but it works using `findViewById`.

So what is missing?

This is my Gradle build file content:

```
  android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true

   }
```

This my java file :

```
   public class cheat_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ActivityCheatActivityBinding binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       binding=ActivityCheatActivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
       View view= binding.getRoot();
       setContentView(view);
       binding.answerTextView.setText("hello world");
        binding.showAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
binding.answerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.question_answer,false)));
        });
    }
}
```

And This is the cheat_activity.xml :

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.application.cheat_activity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="@string/Warning_text"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp" tools:text="Answer"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_answer_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_answer_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "is not working" -- you need to explain in detail what this means. What specifically is happening? "and This is the cheat_activity.xml" -- note that this resource name does not match your binding class name. According to your binding, your layout resource would be `activity_cheat_activity.xml`.

Comment: yes I know the XML file and binding file is not the same but  Lint says that is the only file that was created and there is no file as match my XML file name cheat_activity

Comment: the problem is when i call for instance
 binding.showAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
binding.answerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.question_answer,false)));
the text not change

Comment: when i use find view by id it works 
i don't know why this happen